# create smaller chunks of a file then compress and decompress back into one file

Tags: c#, gzip

I'm trying to create a file transfer application which sends files after compressing them. My main goal was to provide resumable transfer with it, for that purpose, I first create an archive of all the files the user has to send, then I open the archive in a stream and read a chunk of data from it (say a chunk of 2mb), I compress that chunk and decompress it on the receiving side and then append that data into a larger file which will become the main archive.

```
GZipOutputStream gzipout = new GZipOutputStream(File.Create("abc.zip"));
                //reading and compressing the chunk into abc.zip
                do
                {
                    //f is my filestream for the original archive
                    sourceBytes = f.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (sourceBytes == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    gzipout.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                    bytesread += sourceBytes;
                } while (bytesread < chunklength);
            bytesread = 0;



            gzipout.Finish();
            gzipout.Close();
            //encrypting the chunk
            s.EncryptFile("abc.zip","abc.enc");

            //the chunk is sent over here to the receiving side
            //these are the functions on the receiving side
            //decrypting the chunk
            s.DecryptFile("abc.enc","abc1.zip");

            GZipInputStream gzipin=new GZipInputStream(File.OpenRead("abc1.zip"));
            //the chunk is being decompressed and appended into the original archive file
            FileStream temp = File.Open(Path.GetFileName("originalzip.zip"), FileMode.Append);

            int size = 2048;
            byte[] data = new byte[2048];
            while (true)
            {
                size = gzipin.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                if (size != 0)
                    temp.Write(data, 0, size);
                else
                    break;
            }
            temp.Flush();
            temp.Close();
        } while (sourceBytes!=0);
        ExtractAll("originalzip.zip", "testest");
```

The problem is somewhere in the chunking process because if i send the archive as it is, it works, but when i try to make chunks, the receiving archive has a larger size and can't be opened.

Edit: It's fixed, i deleted the previously created chunk before making the new one and it fixed it

Comment: What exception is thrown on what line?

Comment: no exception is thrown, its just that the archive created on the receiving end (After decompressing and appending all the chunks) has a different file size (about a 100kb more) and can't be opened by a zip manager (unexpected end of archive,the original archive opens)

Comment: compressing an already compressed stream almost always have the side effect of growing. If it's already zipped send the zipped chunks, don't compress the chunks again

Comment: its just an archive(a zip file with no compression) and the problem only occurs when i make the chunks, if i compress it again into one large file and then decompress it, the size remains same and zip managers don't give any error opening it.

Comment: Look into the file with a hex editor. Or use tiny chunks of one byte to make the problem more obvious.

Comment: thanks! i looked into it by a hex editor, the first chunk was being written correctly but the others were garbage data, i figured the problem had something to do with the filemode.create, it's not correctly overwriting the previous compressed chunks, instead of overwriting i used file.delete then file.create and it fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is line 11 of your code:

```
f.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
```

Which should change to:

```
gzipout.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
```

I'd say this is corrupting your original archive, appending chunks from the beginning to the end of the file (strange that you don't see errors, maybe you opened it in read/write mode?). And no change is made to abc.zip: maybe you've got a non empty file here left over from an experiment, resulting in an archive on the receiving side that contains several copies of this file.

Comment: no, sorry that's a typo, i was trying some other things and i posted that here, it was originally gzipout.Write(), I've found the solution, it was something to do with the filemode.create, it wasn't probably properly overwriting the previously created chunk(because adding file.delete after using the chunk fixed it)